# Creating es-la/es-xl resources in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, globalization

So, I am in the process of global/localizing an asp.net mvc3 website and have a list of cultures I need to support. Every one has worked well so far but, I have not been able to get the spanish (Latin American) culture code to work. It appears that it is not supported by microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

Is there a way to circumvent this? I know I can add each of the specific country cultures but that actually will not work (specifically in chrome) when the browser is set to es-la. If I do not find a reasonable workaround for this it is becoming a defect. :(

I would be happy to add any additional detail required. Any help is greatly appreciated. Even if the answer is that I can't really workaround it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider this to be a bit of a hack, but would it work to use the neutral culture "es" for Latin America?  Then any other spanish cultures, such as Spain, would have the specific culture and get used instead if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @DotNet Zebra. This is the approach I ended-up taking. However it does not apparently work in chrome for when es-la is specified as the first choice. It works in every other scenario so we are going forward.

Comment: Wow just what I was looking for! And in case anyone comes looking in the future as an example: `Branding.es-ES.resx` and `Branding.es.resx` both compile. But `Branding.es-LA.resx` will not compile.